# Hadoop Pig - how to set the directory for intermediate results

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig

My Pig jobs are storing intermediate result on my hard drive, which is small. I would like Pig to store these intermediate results on /data. Which setting do I have to change?

Comment: Which is the location is it using now ?

Comment: it is using /tmp/vg00--

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to add the following export in the pig conf file ( /pig.-0.14.0/conf/pig-env.sh):

```
export PIG_OPTS="$PIG_OPTS -Dhadoop.tmp.dir=$path_to_big_hard_drive -Dpig.temp.dir=$path_to_big_hard_drive"
```